# Xpath find a div without children with specific text

Tags: xpath, html-parsing

I need to retrieve a div without children with given text. I have this html

```
<h1>Rest Object</h1>
<div style="background-color: transparent;">
    <div>Title: Rest object</div>
    <div>ID: 2</div>
    <div>Title: Rest object Copy</div>
    <div>Full text: This is the full text. ID: 2</div>
    <div>Value: 0.564</div>
    <div>Timestamp: 2017-06-14 11:35:40</div>
</div>
```

I want to find `<div>ID: 2</div>`. How? I tried

```
xpath=(//div)
```

and it returns first div. I tried to use

```
xpath=(//div[not(div)])
```

and it returns
`<div>Title: Rest object</div>`.

**UPDATE**. Now I know I could you index.

```
 xpath=(//div[not(div)][2])
```

`<div>ID: 2</div>`.

What if I don't know the index.

which returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the needed `div` is to use `starts-with()` function:

```
//div[starts-with(.,'ID:')]
```

---

`boolean starts-with(string, string)` - Returns `true` if the first argument *string* starts with the second argument *string*; otherwise returns `false`

---

To restrict the search to `div` element which has no children you may use `count(*)` function:

```
//div[starts-with(.,'ID:')][count(*)=0]
```

Comment: Yes, it works!
`xpath=(//div[starts-with(.,'ID')])`.

What if I want a div without children?

Comment: @YanKhonski, try `[not(./*)]` predicate